# Getting error while calling jqgrid through Ajax request on MVC3 : error 80020101

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

The following code throwing error like "Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101"

on the file `jquery-1.8.3.js`:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Details = '@Url.Content("~/Controller/ActionResult1?id=")';

        var id= $("#id").val();
        $('#pager').hide();

        Details = Details + id;

        alert(PropertyDetails);
        $("#list").jqGrid({

            url: Details,
            datatype: 'xml',
            cache: false,
            mtype: 'GET',
            width: 600,
            height: 234,
            colNames: ['Name', 'Address', 'Type'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 20, xmlmap: 'Name' },
            { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 20, xmlmap: 'Address' },
            { name: 'Type', index: 'Type', width: 20, xmlmap: 'Type' },
            ],

            xmlReader: { repeatitems: false },
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            sortname: 'invid',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            loadonce: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            scroll: false,
            altRows: true,
            loadComplete: function () {
                if ($('#list').getGridParam('records') > 10) {
                    $('#pager').show();
                }
            }

        });

    });

    </script>

<table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table> 
<div id="pager"></div>  

my controller side.

 public ActionResult ActionResult1(string id)
        {
// code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

modify script like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
         var Details = '@Url.Content("~/Controller/ActionResult1?id=';

         var id= $("#id").val();
         $('#pager').hide();

         Details = Details + id+'")';


        alert(PropertyDetails);
        $("#list").jqGrid({

            url: Details,
            datatype: 'xml',
            cache: false,
            mtype: 'GET',
            width: 600,
            height: 234,
            colNames: ['Name', 'Address', 'Type'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 20, xmlmap: 'Name' },
            { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 20, xmlmap: 'Address' },
            { name: 'Type', index: 'Type', width: 20, xmlmap: 'Type' },
            ],

            xmlReader: { repeatitems: false },
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            sortname: 'invid',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            loadonce: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            scroll: false,
            altRows: true,
            loadComplete: function () {
                if ($('#list').getGridParam('records') > 10) {
                    $('#pager').show();
                }
            }

        });

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: I think sudarshan's code is fine except for the part I edited

Comment: Yes,but for the future searches would be nice to be a quality answer.

Comment: thanks guys, i resloved this problem, the problem is, i am calling jquery-1.8.3.js file in multiple places like shared path and page itself. i removed this in page level, then its worked for me